# How to test a WPF app in different screen resolutions? Is there any emulator available?

Tags: wpf, testing, emulation

The problem :- I have to test an APP in a landscape display (which is a digital standee) and is there any emulator which I can test with?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking for simulator.

You can run the simulator directly. It should be installed somewhere like C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\14.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe. The emulators are Hyper-V images of the target OS.

I am generally tasting my WPF application by changing the screen resolution. i.e Right click on desktop > Display settings > Advanced display settings > Resolution. From here you can change any resolution, and verify you application in different resolution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to install Windows Simulator on Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Are you sure that simulator works for WPF, I read that it only works for UWP